# Different normal forms for the table

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I am confused with the normalization topic,so please give the normalization forms of the table contains the columns as shown below

> EMPID,   EMPNAME,   DATEOFJOIN,          PREVIOUS_EXP,      DESIGNATION,        MANAGER,      Email,     Mobile,      Location ,   IMAGE

Comment: sir,can u help me to write this table in different normalization forms just like 1st normal form : related columns 2nd normal form : related columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry much about normalization if you have only this much details for a database, you can organize your data as per your requirements. The below form looks good for me.

```
EMPID, EMPNAME, DATEOFJOIN, PREVIOUS_EXP, DESIGNATION, Location

EMPID, Email, Mobile

EMPID, MANAGER

EMPID, IMAGE
```

Comment: sir,can u help me to write this table in different normalization forms just like       1st normal form :  related columns               2nd normal form : related columns...........................